# Android: Cannot read data sent from Arduino via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I'm sending integer sensor values from Arduino via bluetooth and I try to read these integers in the Android app I'm writing. I'm trying to show the values I get in a text view, but when I connect my device with the bluetooth module and open the app nothing happens. Please help

This is the code for Arduino:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial ble(8, 7); // RX, TX

void setup() {
    // Open serial port
    Serial.begin(9600);
   // Begin bluetooth serial port communication
   ble.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);

   Serial.println("Sending Bluetooth Message...");
   ble.write(sensorValue);
   delay(1000);
}
```

and the code of my Android app:

```
package com.example.fotini.eog;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Handler;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BluetoothSocket bt_socket;
    private InputStream in_stream;
    boolean kill_worker = false;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    TextView myLabel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLabel);

        BluetoothAdapter bt_adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothDevice bt_device = bt_adapter.getRemoteDevice("60:64:05:D1:34:38");

       bt_adapter.cancelDiscovery();
       try {
            bt_socket = bt_device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
            bt_socket.connect();
       } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }

       startListeningThread();

  }

  public void startListeningThread()  {
       try {
           in_stream = bt_socket.getInputStream();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       Thread worker = new Thread(new Runnable()   {
           @Override
           public void run()   {
               while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !kill_worker) {
                   try {
                        //Read the incoming response
                        while (in_stream.available() > 0) {

                           final int readMessage = in_stream.read();
                           myLabel.setText(readMessage);

                           handler.post(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                                myLabel.setText(readMessage);
                           }
                       });
                     }
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                    kill_worker = true;
                }
             }
          }
     });

    worker.start();
}
```

Comment: please have a look here if it helps : http://mangoprojects.info/arduino/android-wireless-remote-switch-control-home-appliances-android-bluetooth-arduino/

Comment: In that project the Arduino receives data, which is the opposite of what I'm trying to do...

Comment: Have you checked, if the worker thread exits, because of an IOException?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't exit